# Adding rows values for specific entries

Tags: r

I have budget data on a set of districts. I also have a district, DH, that had 2 additional regions merged into it after 2012. The budget values are given separately in the data frame for the year 2011 for the three parts that were later merged into one. I want to add those values into the district DH's values for the year 2011.

I know I can use column sums, but I don't know how to use column sum for all variables using the if/else condition

```
columnSums(df) if District==1 | District==2
```

The above code is definitely not going to work because it is not in the correct form, but this is the basic gist of the code I want to use to sum all variables for the districts 1 and 2 and add it to the values of the district 'DH'.

Comment: You may want to take a look into `?by`.

Comment: I tried the following but that does not work: library(dplyr)
Budget_panel %>%
  mutate(cat_b = if_else(cat_b == "GT461", "GT462", "TSH") )%>%
  group_by(cat_b) %>%

Answer (score 1):

You have to alter the district column or do create a new one that identifies the districts that belong together. Here is some pseudo code:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(District = if_else(District == 2, 1, District)) %>%
  group_by(District) %>%
  summarise(col_to_sum = sum(col_to_sum))
```

Comment: I am wondering why my post was voted down? I have asked a question that can be relevant to a lot of coders on this forum